# Rules of powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I am working on an integral part of it involves $$\int (3t^2-4)^\frac{5}{2}$$

Obviously the sub is $$\Biggl[3\Biggl(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}sec(t)\Biggl)^2-4\Biggl]^{\frac{5}{2}}$$

which becomes

$$2\sqrt{tan^2(t)}^5$$ But how is that possible the $5$ is supposed to stay with whats inside the square root I fail to see where you can just pull out the 5 from inside the radical and say that its actually the radical and everything inside to the 5th power and not just what is inside the radical to the fifth power.

Comment: It should be $$32\left(\sqrt{\tan^2 x}\right)^5$$ $32,$ not $2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property of exponents that matters is $\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}=\left(a^c\right)^b$  for $a \gt 0$.  If you have a square root sign, $b$ or $c$ is $\frac 12$ and this still applies.  In fact, when you write $(3t^2-4)^{\frac 52}$ you are not indicating whether this is $\sqrt{(3t^2-4)^5}$ or $\left(\sqrt{3t^2-4}\right)^5$.  It doesn't matter because they are equal by the preceding property.

Comment: I just edited  to fix a small typo